# Ember js hello world program is not working

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to create a hello world program in ember js.
below is the code

```
        <html>
        <head>
            <script src="libraries/jquery.js"></script>
            <script src="libraries/handlebars.js"></script>
            <script src="libraries/ember.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <script type="text/x-handlebars">
        {{#view App.UserView }}
        <b>Name:</b> {{person.name}}
        {{/view}}
        </script>
        <button onclick="btnTest_OnClick()" id="btnTest">Click me to change</button>
          <script type="text/javascript"> 
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    window.App = Ember.Application.create();
                    //create class
                    App.Person = Ember.Object.extend({
                        id: 0,
                        name: ""
                    });
                    //create instance of class
                    var person = App.Person.create();
                    person.name = "Duncan";
                    person.id = 0;
                    //create controller
                    App.userController = Ember.Object.create({
                        content: person,
                        changeModel: function () {
                            this.content.set('name', 'Joe');
                        }
                    });
                    //view
                     App.UserView = Ember.View.extend({
                        nameBinding: 'App.userController.content.name'            
                    });
               }); 
              function btnTest_OnClick() {
                    App.userController.changeModel();
                }
        </script> 
        </body>
        </html>
```

it is not giving any error message but the name is not displayed on browser
could you please help me out??

Answer (score 0):

You can't run emberjs like that. Move your app code to an app.js file and include that file. You don't need the document ready. Ember handles that for you.